# Using Drush To Download Modules When You Dont Really Know The Name

Tags: drush

Hello im a drush newbie and im enjoying ints functionality. Years ago i saw a video of someone using drush to download modules and if he got the project name slighly wrong t would show him some alterntives in his command line interface.

Did i imagine this or is it possible?

Thanks

ps i just use drush dl modulename at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think your imagination did the trick! but the closest thing I can imagine is to use this [sandbox module](https://drupal.org/sandbox/Letharion/1833420)

> Allows you to search for modules from drush